# Проблема с ассинхронным скриптом python

Tags: python, парсер

есть вот такой код

```
from distutils import errors
from distutils.log import error
import encodings
from fileinput import close
from random import random
from traceback import print_tb
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import random
import unicodedata
import sys
import gc
if sys.version_info[0] == 3 and sys.version_info[1] >= 8 and sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    policy = asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy()
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(policy)
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
useragent=UserAgent()
CategoryDict={}
All_pages_list=[]
All_items_list=[]
All_items_list_try=[]

semaph=asyncio.Semaphore(15)
async def get_site_content(url):# Список ссылок на товары
    
    async with semaph:
        headers={'User-Agent':useragent.random}
        connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=30)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers,connector=connector) as session:
            async with session.request(method="GET",url=url) as resp:
                
                text = await resp.text(encoding="utf-8",errors="replace")
                SoupText= BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")
                header=SoupText.find('h1').text
                current_page=SoupText.find(class_='pgsn').text
                itemslist=SoupText.findAll(class_='desc')
                await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
                for el in itemslist:
                    All_items_list.append("https://069.net.ua"+el.a.get('href'))

                print(f"{header} {current_page} done")
                

                return BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")


async def get_item_content(url): #разбор страницы товара   
    semaph1=asyncio.Semaphore(1)
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=30)
    async with semaph1:
        headers={'User-Agent':useragent.random}
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers,connector=connector) as session:
            async with session.request(method="GET",url=url) as resp:
                text = await resp.text(encoding="utf-8",errors="replace")
                SoupText= BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")
                item_name=SoupText.find('h1').text
                item_code=SoupText.find_all(class_='g-r')[-2].text
                photo_link="https://069.net.ua"+SoupText.find(id="s-gal-bp").img.get("src")
                item_color=SoupText.find_all(class_='g-r')[-2].text
                size_list=SoupText.find_all('option')
                temp_list=[]
                rand=random.randint(1,5)
                if rand == 3:
                    All_items_list.append(asyncio.ensure_future(asyncio.sleep(7)))
                for item in size_list:
                    if item.text!="Виберіть":
                        temp_list.append(item.text)
                size_list=temp_list
                item_category=SoupText.find_all(itemprop='name')[1].text
                try:
                    item_price=SoupText.find(class_="prcn").text
                except:
                    item_price="no name"
                if len(size_list)!=0:    
                   item_availability="В наявності"
                else:
                    item_availability="Відсутній"
                item_brand=SoupText.find_all(itemprop='name')[2].text
                await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1,10))
                print()
                print("===========================================")
                print("назва товару -"+str(item_name))
                print("код товару -"+str(item_code))
                print("посилання на фото товару -"+str(photo_link))
                print("колір - "+str(item_color))
                print("розміри- "+str(size_list))
                print("категорія -"+str(item_category))
                print("ціна - "+str(item_price))
                print("наявність - "+str(item_availability))
                print("бренд - "+str(item_brand))
                print("===========================================")
                with open(f"try/{time.time()}.html","w", encoding="utf-8") as file :
                    file.write(text)
                await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(3,5))
                return BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")




url="https://069.net.ua/ua/"
req = requests.get(url)
src=req.text
Categories_soup=BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml").find(id="tabs")
CategoriesList=Categories_soup.find_all(class_='sta')
for category in CategoriesList:
    categorySoup=BeautifulSoup(str(category),"lxml")
    name=categorySoup.text
    href="https://069.net.ua"+category['href']
    CategoryDict[name]=href
with open("files/Categories.json","w", encoding="utf-8") as file :
        json.dump((CategoryDict),file,indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)
for key in CategoryDict:
    url=CategoryDict[key]
    req = requests.get(url)
    src=req.text
    LastLink=BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml").find(id='flt-opt').find_all(class_="pgs")
    LastLink=int(LastLink[-2].text)
    for a in range(1,LastLink+1):
        page_url=url+f"?page={a}/"
        rand=random.randint(0,10)
        if rand == 3:
            All_pages_list.append(asyncio.ensure_future(asyncio.sleep(5)))
        All_pages_list.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_site_content(page_url)))
    print(key+" "+"done")

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*All_pages_list))
    print('--------------------------')
    print('second loop')
    print('--------------------------')
    print(len(All_items_list))
    gc.collect()
    loop= asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for el in All_items_list:
        All_items_list_try.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_item_content(el)))
 -# loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*All_items_list_try))
```

выдает вот такую ошибку -

```
d:\Fakework\69_parser\try.py:139: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  loop= asyncio.get_event_loop()
d:\Fakework\69_parser\try.py:141: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  All_items_list_try.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_item_content(el)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Fakework\69_parser\try.py", line 142, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*All_items_list_try))
  File "C:\Users\Chikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 633, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\Chikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 600, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\Chikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1860, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Chikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\selectors.py", line 324, in select
    r, w, _ = self._select(self._readers, self._writers, [], timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Chikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\selectors.py", line 315, in _select
    r, w, x = select.select(r, w, w, timeout)
ValueError: too many file descriptors in select()
```

Что делать я уже не знаю,перерыл много источников,надеюсь на совет знатаков
Строка вызывающая ошибку помечена "-#"

Comment: "Есть вот такой код" уже традиционно значит, "писал не я, как работает - не знаю". "перерыл много источников" без нарытых результатов обычно равно "сразу написал сюда". Если я неправ, поправьте меня и приведите наиболее правдоподобную  версию из "многих" источников.
В любом случае настоятельно рекомендую (минимум 1 и 2): 1) привести полный (!) текст ошибки и указать, к какой строке выдана ошибка; 2) пояснить, где, собственно, этот `select`? В приведённом коде его вообще нет; 3) желательно привести минимально (!) воспроизводимый код, как и положено по правилам сайта, а не все эти строки.

Comment: Писал я и искал информацию несколько часов,схожих ошибок не нашел. Полный текст ошибки  в исправленном коде вопроса,коротко о том как работает код - Сначала парсятся категории ->поскольку каждая категория содержит несколько страниц,то парсится каждая страница->с них получаем ссылки на страницы каждого товара(это все делает функция  get_site_content()).  Потом при попытке спарсить именно стараницу товара появляется данная ошибка

Comment: Странно, что не нашли схожих. Вот я нашел за пять минут: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675410/python-asyncio-aiohttp-valueerror-too-many-file-descriptors-in-select-on-win>. У вас сколько сокетов? И что дало использование`ProactorEventLoop`?
Ну, как минимум, ошибка добавлена, возможно, кто и ответит на её базе.

Comment: Если у вас в списке `All_items_list` очень много элементов — вы пытаетесь функцией `get_item_content` скачать их все одновременно и ваша система не выдерживает такой колоссальной нагрузки (или, говоря более формально, вы упёрлись в лимит открытых файловых дескрипторов, которые можно запихнуть в select)

Comment: @andreymal, я правильно понимаю, что `ProactorEventLoop` как раз и может помочь?

Comment: @Сергей я не разбирался, как работает asyncio в винде. Но, думаю, дудосить сайты таким кодом это в любом случае плохая идея)

Comment: Пробовал добовлять ProactorEventLoop(),в таком виде 
if sys.platform == 'win32':
        loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)  

выдает много подобных ошибок: task: <Task pending name='Task-132' coro=<get_site_content() running at d:\Fakework\69_parser\try.py:29> cb=[gather.<locals>._done_callback() at C:\Users\Chikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:720]>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!

Comment: В общем, схожую ошибку я вам нашел. @andreymal о той же причине пишет, по факту. Туда и копайте. Кстати, если код написан вами, то наличие `asyncio.get_event_loop()` выглядит странно. Так давно не пишут, а в каком-нибудь 3.11. код и вообще может перестать работать - лучше исправить (но это не относится к вашей ошибке).

Comment: Вообще, у вас весь код какой-то странный и запутанный. Вот например по сути то же самое, но без странностей https://pastebin.com/JQ4mhW2v